# Subscribe customer for some plan

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using checkout payment method for user like [there](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). It's button that calls stripe payment form. Let suppose that user pays 10$ for basic plan. After that i have some token `tok_103uPJ28QwVoVFZsNqTEluiP`. I want to know on server-side how much money user paid and how should i subscribe him on basic plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step, after you have a token, is to [create a Customer with a plan](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions).

Comment: Yes, from doc: It's worth noting that Checkout doesn't actually create charges—it only creates tokens. You can use those tokens to create the actual charge on your server